# After click submit button get 500 Internal server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently testing my application in live server, and one thing which I found is when I press submit button I get this type of error

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST EstimatesViewModels/convert?Id=61&roomId=59 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
convert_estimate @ ViewConvertInfo?id=61:594
success @ ViewConvertInfo?id=61:579
j @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
x @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
save_estimate @ ViewConvertInfo?id=61:564
onclick @ ViewConvertInfo?id=61:517
```

Interesting, when I run application in local machine I didnt get this type of error. 
When I open script

```
 function convert_estimate() {
        //save_estimate();
        //var estId = document.getElementById("estId").value;
        //var roomId = document.getElementById("roomId").value;
        var estId = $("#estId").val();
        //var roomId = $("#roomId").val();
        var roomId = $('input[type=radio][name=RoomOption]:checked').attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "post",
            url: "/EstimatesViewModels/convert?Id=" + estId + "&roomId=" + roomId,

            success: function (data) {
                data;
            },
            error: function () {
                swal("Oops", "Please select one of avaliable options!", "error");
                $('#changeClass').removeClass('disabled');
                $('#changeClassIcon').removeClass('icon-spinner4');
                $('#changeClassIcon').removeClass('spinner');
                $('#changeClassIcon').addClass('icon');
                $('#changeClassIcon').addClass('icon-check');
                $('#changeClass').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    }
```

I get two error here, but I dont understand what is problem here since in local machine everything work perfect without any error.
The error is in line

```
 $.ajax({
```

and also

```
convert_estimate();
```

Any help guys, what could be the issue ?

[image]

Comment: `500` = Internal Server Error = You have an unhandled exception being thrown in your *server side* code. Attach the debugger to investigate what it is or add logging.

Comment: Check the error log created on the server

Comment: You'll need to check the server logs. the js works correctly the exception is from the backend

Comment: "Internal Server Error" means there was an error *on the server*.  Not in the JavaScript code.  Check the actual response from the AJAX request (in your browser's debugging tools) to see if the response body contains information about the error.  Check error logs, etc.  The server is telling you something went wrong, you have to go find out *what* before you can fix it.

Comment: How to find this log file ?

Comment: There are *100s of ways* to implement logging. You'll have to find the sources for the MVC Controller that implements "EstimatesViewModels" and then debug or analyze from there.

Comment: @Joe123: You might not *have* a "log file", if you never implemented logging in your application.  We know absolutely nothing about your server-side application.  All we know is that, when you run it, you get an unspecified error.  So you need to debug, examine the output, possibly add some logging/tracing of some kind of re-deploy to get more information about the error, etc.  Once you can show us what the error is and what code is causing it, we can help with that.  At this time you aren't able to show us either of those things, so we can't help.

Comment: @David Check the image  in post, this is what I get in console.log

Comment: @Joe123: Yes, that's exactly what you'd already indicated.  And, as already advised, you will need to determine what *from the server* is causing that error.  The first thing you should do is examine the response body in your browser's debugging tools, as it may contain information about the problem.  (Or, if it doesn't, a simple configuration change may allow it to contain useful information.)

Comment: @David Thank you for advice, I will debugg right now :)

Comment: At first glance, you're using query string for this line: `url: "/EstimatesViewModels/convert?Id=" + estId + "&roomId=" + roomId`. I suggest you to use `data` parameter and `@Url.Action()` helper to generate URL instead. Also since `roomId` is `undefined`, try checking against `undefined` before using AJAX callback.